# Difference between "talk back at you" and "talk back to you"

Tags: meaning

I am not sure if they both mean the same thing, but if they don't mean the same thing is it possible that "talk back at you" implies a more aggressive opposition than "talk back to you"?

Comment: "Talk back *at* you" sounds like a colloquialism.  I assume it means more or less the same as "Talk back *to* you".

Comment: Where are your samples? Where did you hear this? No context, no good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "talk to" implies a two-way conversation.  Sometimes we want to make a point of saying that there was no conversation, and that one person was talking but not listening.  In those cases "talk at" is used.

> After talking to my teacher on the phone, mum came to my room and talked at me for half an hour about my "attitude".

I guess you could use "talk back at me" to mean "the person replied to me but didn't listen to what I said".

Comment: Talk to implies a two-way conversation?? Not sure it does at all. "I talked to him for ten minutes last night, but he never said anything at all".